# While return bad result

Tags: php, math, while-loop

```
$total=0;
$q=$db->query("SELECT money FROM users");
 while($r=$db->fetch_row($q))
 {
  $total+=$r['money'];
  }
```

What's wrong with this ? All the time returns zero...

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if your query actually succeeded? You're just assuming nothing could ever go wrong.

Comment: Might just `SELECT SUM(money) as total FROM users`

Comment: @GasKa: the query SYNTAX might be fine, but there's more to running a query than just having the correct sql. you need to check if the `->query()` call succeeded.

Comment: How many times does the loop execute?  What's your expected result?  Is 'money' 0 for all rows?  What is the response from the SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `SELECT SUM(money) as total FROM users`, however the way you are doing it you need to use a different fetch.  `fetch_array()` with `MYSQLI_ASSOC` or `fetch_assoc()` as `fetch_row()` is a numerically indexed array:

```
while($r = $q->fetch_assoc())
{
    $total += $r['money'];
}
```

Or use `fetch_row()` and `$r[0]`.